# How to set Post Value of Request

Tags: magento2, request

I have already know how to get the `POST` value of Request.

I used to use this code below to get the value:

```
$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

But how can I set the value of `POST`. Something like:

```
$this->getRequest()->setPostValue('value',$value);
```

or

```
$this->getRequest()->set('value',$value);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: `$this->getRequest()->setPostValue('value',$value);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can set value using `setPostValue()` check below for set of array,

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Model;

class Request extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject
{
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    parent::__construct($data);
}

public function setPostCustomValue(){
    /* for single value */
    $this->request->setPostValue('test','store my value');

    /* for multiple array */
    $post = [
            'customer' => [
                'firstname' => 'test firstname',
                'lastname' => 'test lastname',
                'email' => 'example@domain.com',
                'default_billing' => '_item1',
            ],
            'address' => ['_item1' => []],
        ];
    $this->request->setPostValue('customarray',$post);
}
```

Comment: If I have already have the `customer` and `address` key in my PostValue, It change the value or insert the new key-value?

Comment: It just update the value if aleady exist then update otherwise keep it

Comment: You can set single value as well as array value.

Answer (score 4):

You can try below code to set param

```
$this->getRequest()->setParam('value',$value);
```

Comment: It just change the Param, not the post value.

Comment: it will work, this param will be set to the post data, if this param  is already in post data it will overwrite that value

Answer (score 3):

You can write in you controller and it is the way worked for me:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductComments\Controller\Post;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;    

class Index extends Action
{
    public function __construct(
        ....
        ....
    ) {
        ....
        ....
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getRequest()->setPostValue('timestamp', '24343256534345');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is the correct answer!

Comment: Thank You. It worked for me as well. It will change the posted value for 'timestamp'. In your case change it to 'value'.

Comment: Yes. It's easy to understand!